# IndexError: list index out of range-Python

Tags: python, list

I'm analyzing an Apache access log file with python and I want to extract the `Referrer` field out of it. `Referrer` is located at the 9th position splitting it using space as the delimiter. (All together there are more than 9 fields after splitting using spaces.) Following code write the extracted filed in to a file.

```
for line in open('log'):
    referer = line.split(' ')[9]
    fo.write(referer +'\n')
```

The problem here is the referrer field is written to the file, but the program gives following error? What could be the problem?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 18, in <module>
    referer = line.split(' ')[9]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

sample log file line:

```
112.135.128.20 - [13/May/2013:23:55:04 +0530] "GET /SVRClientWeb/ActionController HTTP/1.1" 302 2 "https://www.example.com/sample" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/10B329" GET /SVRClientWeb/ActionController - HTTP/1.1 www.test.com
```

Comment: It means not all lines look the same. There are probably some lines shorter than this one.

Comment: Maybe one of the lines is shorted, which breaks your script.

Comment: Include a try/except code that prints out the line that raises the exception so you can verify if that line does not follow the pattern

Answer (score 0):

There probably is an empty line somewhere in the file (maybe an extra newline at the end), or just a shorter one.

You can (for example) use enumerate to find it!

```
for i, line in enumerate(f):
```

Answer (score 0):

It means one of the line in your file does not have [9] index after splitting. Check file. Print line Number to check where is the error

```
i=0
for line in open('log'):
    referer = line.split(' ')[9]
    fo.write(referer +'\n')
    print i
    i+=1
```

You will find line number and check line at that place in vim or any editor.